# How to make Grapevine REST Server only on current running Windows Session

Tags: c#, rest, httplistener, grapevine

I run a [Grapevine](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine) REST Server (The current implementation of Grapevine relies on the features exposed by System.Net.HttpListener) in a C# application on a Windows Session (User A), on localhost:8888 for example.

If I leave the user A session open with the executable running and log on to a new User B session, I access my REST server at localhost: 8888.

Can we restrict access to the REST server on the session that started it?

Comment: By "session" you mean restrict it to the currently logged on user? Such that if you switch users on Windows, the new user can't access the still-running instance?

Comment: @ScottOffen Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grapevine uses the built-in [`HttpListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.0) in .NET, which you can access and configure directly using the `Advanced` property of the `RestServer` class.

```cs
var server = new Grapevine.Server.RestServer();
var listener = server.Advanced; // This is an HttpListener object
```

You can configure authentication in any way you could if you were using `HttpListener` out of the box. A good starting point might be the [`AuthenticationSchemes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.authenticationschemes?view=netframework-4.0) property.

If traditional authentication methods don't fit your use case, you might want to try to get the logged in user when your application starts, and then add an event handler on `server.Router.BeforeRouting` that automatically returns a [401 or 403](https://www.loggly.com/blog/http-status-code-diagram/) if the request isn't from that user. I haven't actually tried it myself, but that's where I would go with it.